# Can I help a failing water pump by removing the rad cap?

Tags: coolant

I'm on a trip and my water pump is starting to leak. The rad and overflow are a sealed system. If I left the pressure cap off the overflow will that help the water pump - less pressure? The temp on my drive tomorrow will be 25 celsius.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

25 °C is warm enough that you would want normal thermal capacity of your system to prevent overheating. Your vehicle system is sealed to maintain a higher-than-ambient pressure, which by extension of the laws of physics, also maintains a higher-than-100 °C boiling point of the coolant within. Releasing the pressure or not allowing it to be created by having an open system/cap will result in faster boiling of the coolant, causing evaporation. It may also prevent appropriate heat transfer from the engine to the outside air via the radiator.

In a closed system, the pressure of the coolant is not going to affect the water pump to any appreciable amount. The pump does not pressurize the system, it merely moves the coolant from one location to another.

Removing the pressure from the system with an open cap may reduce the leak (or it might not) but it will reduce the cooling of the overall system, along with the aforementioned loss of coolant.

Comment: I think the issue is that any coolant you might save by lowering the pressure will be offset by the loss of coolant due to boiling.